# Why does my C code for inserting an element into a hash tree work in Main() but not when I call it via function?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm fairly certain this has something to do with pointers and the function using copies instead, but I'm not sure how...because I've inserted the pointer as a parameter for create();

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h> 
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list {
    string word;
    struct list *next;
}
linkedList; 

struct list* create (string newWord) {
    linkedList *new = malloc(sizeof(newWord));
    new->word = newWord;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

struct list* insert (struct list *theList, string newValue) {
    linkedList *anotherOne = create(newValue);
    anotherOne->next = theList;
    return anotherOne;
}

int hash (string name) {
    return strlen(name);
}

void hashInsert (struct list *theList, string newValue) {
    theList = create(newValue);
    }

int main(void) {
   linkedList *names[24] = {NULL};
   int num = hash("heey");
 //  names[num] = create("heey"); // <- this code works when I uncomment it
   hashInsert(names[num], "heey"); // <-- this causes a segfault.. idk why
   printf("%s", names[num]->word);
}
```

Comment: your create is wrong:
sizeof(linkedList) != sizeof(string) (aka char *)

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(newWord))` is not allocating enough memory for the `struct`. It should be `linkedList *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));`

Comment: Unrelated, it's been almost a week since I cursed the authors of `cs50` for type aliasing `char *` to `string`. Someday I'm going to meet the neanderthal that thought that was a helpful idea. This code is an example of how hiding pointer types in aliases shrouds the fact that `sizeof` is actually delivering the size of a pointer (which is wrong even if corrected, as it should be `sizeof *new`, but that's another issue).Just... grrrr.

Comment: @WhozCraig *it's been almost a week since I cursed the authors of cs50 for type aliasing `char *` to `string`. Someday I'm going to meet the neanderthal that thought that was a helpful idea.* What hideous evil did neanderthals do to you that you would insult their intelligence so viciously?  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `hashInsert` function creates a local copy of the pointer (`theList`), you modify said local copy, but the actual pointer in your `main` function is still set to `NULL`. Calling `printf` on that is the cause of your segmentation fault.

You can resolve this issue by passing a pointer to the pointer to your function

```
void hashInsert(string list **theList, string newValue) {
    *theList = create(newValue);
}
```

and then call it

```
hashInsert(&names[num], "heey");
```

This way, you modify the value of the pointer from `main`.

**EDIT**

Also, as the comments state, your `malloc` does indeed not allocate enough memory, you also need some memory to store the next list pointer.

Comment: It works! I've been struggling with pointers, but...pointers to pointers? Never heard of those. Do you have any recommended tutorials/links so I can learn more? Very confused atm...

Comment: I'm not sure about tutorials, perhaps someone else can help you with that. But in general, think of a pointer as an integer with the address of whatever value you're looking for. So a pointer to a pointer is simply the address of a pointer that stores the address of a value, it's exactly the same as any other pointer. The point here is that you want to modify the value of your pointer, so you send the function the address to it, so that it can change the value, i.e. point it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with you `hashInsert` function. It takes the pointer by value (so the original pointer you pass isn't modified). There's a much better way to go about this-

```
struct list* hashInsert(char* string){
    return create(string);
}
```

A few points aside from that, don't use `string`, always use `char*` since that what it really is. I see you're using some library, but you're better off simply including the proper headers yourself, in this case, you should include `stdlib.h` since it contains the definition of `malloc()`.

Comment: unfortunately, some guys at harvard when designing a programming course.

Comment: @ShaheAnsar *Who the hell thought that was a good idea?*  **Thought** had nothing to do with it...